# Text editor - line to offset data structure

Tags: data-structures

When writing a text editor, there needs to be a data structure that simply can convert a line number to a document offset. A naive implementation would be an (array) list of document offsets, but this has the disadvantage that when inserting text at the beginning, all (!) higher line offsets would have to be incremented and/or shifted (for entered new lines). What tree-like data structure is recommended to only have to update ideally 1 or just a few elements - by allowing the access of the document offset to become a little bit slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. One way is to amortize the cost of maintaining those offsets. If you're inserting text, it doesn't matter what the offsets of the latter lines are until you need to access them. You could just keep a "dirty flag" that says that the offsets after line X are invalid and must be updated. Then, if the user scrolls down a few pages, you only have to recalculate the offsets of the lines the user needs to access. If you want, you could have a background task that recalculates offsets asynchronously.

There are several optimizations of that, including creating "blocks" of multiple lines. Say, for example, you allocate blocks of 16 megabytes. You keep the offset of each block, and then parse the blocks when needed to find the line offsets. Computers these days are incredibly fast. Parsing a 16 megabyte buffer of text to find the start of each line takes a few microseconds: not something a user is going to notice.

I discussed this at some length in my blog post, http://blog.mischel.com/2011/12/02/designing-a-better-text-file-viewer/